# Refactor Jquery code into function for reuse

Tags: jquery

Looking for some assistance if possible.

I have created some jquery code that does the job, but i feel is a bit cluncky, and would like to refactor it correctly...

At the moment the code responds to a click by the user, it checks on server if the user is allowed to vote, if so, it processes the vote via ajax, and moves the vote accordingly.

However, it is currently set up to run only when the "vote up" link is clicked, where it adds one to the vote count. What I also want to do is detract 1 from the vote count when the user clicks on the link with class="vote down", but i dont want to repeat the same code all over again, for this.

Wondering if there was anyway to package all the code into a function, and say "add one if vote up is clicked, detract one if vote down is clicked.

Many thanks

```
<a href="link class="vote up"> Vote Up </a>
<a href="link class="vote down"> Vote Down</a>




        $('body#true .voteUp').click(function(){

        // Get the song meaning
        $thisLink = $(this);
        var idSm = $(this).parents("div:eq(1)").attr("id");
            //Validate that user isnt rating their own song meaning
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8500/mxRestore/model/mdl_songs.cfc?method=getRateSm&returnFormat=json&queryformat=column', 
            {idSm: idSm}, 
            function(data){
                var bVoteAllowed = data.ROWCOUNT < 1;
                if(bVoteAllowed){
                // User can vote
                    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8500/mxRestore/model/mdl_songService.cfc?method=rateSm&returnFormat=json&queryformat=column', 
                    {idSm:idSm,action:true})
                                   // Change vote accordingly
                    var totalQuantity = 0;
                    var quantity = $thisLink.parent().parent().children('.rateValue').text();
                    quantity = parseInt(quantity);
                    totalQuantity = quantity + 1; 
                    $thisLink.parent().parent().children('.rateValue').text(String(totalQuantity)).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
                }else {

                    $thisLink.text("you are not allowed to vote")   
                }

            })
            return false

    })
```

Comment: `body#true` is unnecessary and can slow things down. Just use `#true`. Even better, I'd write it this way `#true a.voteUp`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...why is this an improved method? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var vote = function(value) {
    // ...
};

$('body#true .voteUp').click(function() {
    return vote(+1);
});

$('body#true .voteDown').click(function() {
    return vote(-1);
});
```

Replace `...` with the body of the function you've already defined. You can use the value passed to `vote()` to determine whether it should be voted up or down.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. There seems to be a little issue with the code however. It doesnt seem to be recognising the "idSm" variable in the vote function, whenever I call it. Its saying the variable is undefined...would you know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.voteUp, .voteDown').click(function(){
   //do your processing, vote checking etc


    if ($(this).hasClass('voteUp')){
       //perform vote up action
    }
    else{
        //perform vote down action
    }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi there, could you be more explicit with regards to this code, as it seems I would still be repeating a large chunck of code in the   if ($(this).hasClass('voteUp')){
           //perform vote up action
    }
    else{
        //perform vote down action
    }
   return false;

section. 

Many thanks